# Intuition on cumulative prospect theory, based on equi-probable outcomes?

Tags: behavioral-economics, risk-aversion

I am trying to build my intuition on the weighting/decision function in cumulative prospect theory. I have a hard time getting a clear picture for even the simple case of equi-probabilities.

Assume ten possible outcomes, 5  positive, 5 negative (hence using 0 as reference point), all with equi-probability 1/10. If I were to use just prospect theory, I would apply a single weighting function on these probabilities, so here the 1/10 would be either over- or under-weighted depending on the choice of the function. Now prospect theory adds a rank-dependent utility function based on the cumulative probability.

In this simple-case of equi-probability, what does this imply? That higher positive and lower negative outcomes are going to be over-weighted, or under-weighted? How can we illustrate that? The standard plot of weights vs probabilities would look quite sad (as we have only one prob), how would the plot of weights versus rank of the outcome look like?

Thanks!